# Why the output decreases in series?

Tags: resistance

I am just confused with below statement 
"A 100 W bulb is connected in series with a room heater. If now 100 W bulb is replaced by a 40 w bulb, the heater output will decrease !"

if I follow this formula P=I*IR

and believe that 100W bulb will have greater resistance than 40W so if I remove 100W (greater resistance and replace it with low resistance 40W bulb) . the heater should pull more voltage for more output ! Then why it says that it decreases ?

Or in short which one has greater resistance 100w OR 40w and why ?

Comment: Source for the statement for context?

Comment: A 100W bulb will have a _lower_ resistance than a 40W bulb. - from the formula you quote, power is proportional to the _square_ of current, so a lower resistance will be more than compensated by a higher current, assuming constant voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Let's completely ignore the heater for the time being.  Let's also assume a 110V mains voltage powering the bulb.  We'll also treat all the items as simple resistors with no effects of self heating taken into account (purely to keep it simple and not overload you with too much information too soon).

We know voltage, and we know wattage, so we can use:
$$
P = \frac{V^2}{R}
$$
Or, re-arranged for R we have:
$$
R = \frac{V^2}{P}
$$

Immediately from that you should be able to see that as you increase P the R will decrease proportionally.  Still, for completeness, let's work through it for each of the bulbs and the heater:

Let's first substitute in our values:
$$
R_{100} = \frac{110^2}{100} $$$$ R_{40} = \frac{110^2}{40}
$$
Work out those sums and you come up with the values:
$$
R_{100} = 121{\Omega}$$$$R_{40} = 302.5\Omega
$$
So now we know the resistance of the bulbs by themselves.  Add to that another resistance for the heater.  Let's assume it's a 1KW heater.  That, by itself, using the same formula, gives us:
$$
R_H = \frac{110^2}{1000} = 12.1\Omega
$$

Now let's put it in series with each of the light bulbs and work out the power from the heater.  First the 100W bulb:
$$
R_T = 121 + 12.1 = 133.1\Omega
$$
$$
I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{110}{133.1} = 0.826A
$$
$$
P = R \times I^2 = 12.1 \times 0.826^2 = 8.265W
$$
Now the 40W bulb:
$$
R_T = 302.5 + 12.1 = 314.6\Omega
$$
$$
I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{110}{314.6} = 0.3497A
$$
$$
P = R \times I^2 = 12.1 \times 0.3497^2 = 1.479W
$$
So you can see a massive reduction in output from the heater with the lower wattage bulb.

Comment: I would say that you second formula says it all: P is in the divisor, so (for the same voltage) a higher power (watt) means a lower resistance (Ohm).

Comment: True.  I have added a note to that effect.

Comment: @Majenko What will be the affect if I rearrange the bulbs in parallel ?

Comment: You mean put the bulb in parallel with the heater? The heater will pump out 1,000W, and the bulb will pump out 100W or 40W depending on which bulb you use. The current drawn from the supply will increase accordingly.

Comment: @Majenko Thanx to you :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the wrong formula for power. An incandescent light bulb is typically meant to be the *only* device in a circuit, which means that the *voltage* would be meant to be constant, not the current.

Since the power relation between voltage and resistance is proportional to the *inverse* of the resistance, a lower power means a higher resistance. As such when the lower power light bulb is placed in series with the other device instead, the voltage divider created drops more voltage across the light bulb and so the power available for the other device decreases.

Answer (score 1):

The resistance of a filament bulb is not constant - it varies (increases) with (increasing) temperature. A hot 40W bulb may well have a higher resistance than a cold 100W bulb.

Answer (score 1):

The 100W light bulb has a lower resistance than 40W. Voltage, power, and current change.
In loads the most constant value is the resistance (with the exception of light bulbs, where the resistance goes up with heating up). If you want to find a working resistance of a 100W light bulb, I = P/V  and then R = V/I. But when several loads are in series, 
first add the resistances, then calculate current, then power. 
In loads, the lower the resistance is, the higher is the power. (inversely proportional)
Provided the voltage is the same.

Figure out this one. If I supply a heater with an extension cord, the lower resistance the extension cord has, the less heat the extension cord produces.
But the lower resistance the heater has, the more heat the heater produces.